# Linux vs Windows 7 Web server performance differences

Tags: windows, linux, performance, apache-2.2, iis

I've tried recently to run some benchmarks and I wanted to check something on Windows and I had discovered huge performance differences between basic HTTP web servers on same machine with Linux and Windows.

I've tested several web servers IIS, Apache2, Lighttpd with different clients Apache's ab and my own client and the result was the same (requests per second) id displaying a
simple HTML web page (default web server page) of a several hundred bytes size:

```
           IIS 7.5   Apache 2.2  Lighttpd
Windows    750         800        -
Linux      -         9,300        22,000
```

I've tried to disable Anti-Virus on Windows but the result hadn't changed.

I don't understand one thing, how on **same** hardware (i5 2.4GHz 4G) 
a web server in the most trivial task can't handle same loads.

Even thou I'm "pro-Linux" I still can't get how can it be so different, Both
64 bit latest operating systems (Linux 2.6.35 and Windows 7) but
yet the difference of an order of magnitude.

Environment:

- OS Windows 7 64 bit pro. Linux Ubuntu 2.6.35
- HW i5 2.4 GHz, 4GB memory
- IIS 7.5, Apache 2.2
- Client ab:
- Called as `ab -c 5 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1/`

Question:

- What can I miss so I get to huge differences?

**Before You Vote To Close:**

Note it is a real question as I'm looking for possible factors that can affect
such huge (order of magnitude) performance differences as I can't believe that
Windows can behave so badly.

**Anybody?**

Comment: Did you disable all useless services/functions in Windows (not sure that all of them can be stopped) ?

Comment: That does seem like a too big difference. I wonder if something different is happening at the network level, eg the Windows `ab` disconnecting and starting a new HTTP connection for each request?

Comment: fwiw, someone found similar results in an article I read a year or two ago. With a lot of fiddling, they were able to reduce the difference, but not as much as one would be happy with.

Comment: 4GB of memory seems "low" for a server with Windows7.

Comment: @bobince I had also written my own client, the results are the same.

Comment: @Rob Do you have any references to this article?

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that IIS is on a client OS also influence the results? I don't imagine the default OS networks settings (for example) being set for being a server when running the desktop version.

Comment: @Artyom - I was going to say I'll look to see if I saved it but I'm afraid I don't have it.

Comment: Before I believe your results, I'd like to understand a bit more about the testing methodology.  Also, the test client connection to the server on localhost is OK, but not exactly how the server will run in the real world. I'd believe the results more if there were multiple clients on remote workstations hitting the server simultaneously.  That's more indicative of a real world situation.  It's entirely possible your client is the bottleneck, not the server!

Comment: @selbie There were two clients the ab and my own same results. Also ab is quite standard client to do things that can load the server with simultaneous connections.

I understand that this setup is not "real world" but I yet expect that the simple TCP/IP server that accepts connections and write responses would have close performance. Finally it is something very basic

Comment: I missed the point that you were running Windows 7.  IIS on Win 7 is known to be throttled down and restricts the number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: @selbie I've tested Apache, IIS and even my own web server (part of CppCMS) and the results were approximately the same (600-800 req/s). Also I used only 5 simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all responders who suggested to use Windows Server 2008...

It was AniVirus. It was not disabled properly.

Once it was disables the performance improved from 600 req/s to 5000 req/s - not as good as Linux but at least reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be more interested to see a Comparison with Server R2. Windows 7 shouldn't be running web servers, though I agree the difference in results seems extreme.

Comment: Not necesarily. Ignore IIS - the TCP stack in 7.0 is having mechanicms to  slow down the creation of new TCP connections.

Comment: @TomTom I still maintain that it's a pretty irrelevant comparison. Microsoft produce two (essentially) operating systems - one for home use, one for server use. They may be based on the same foundations but they're fundamentally very different operating systems.

Ubuntu has completely different design principles which really means you have to compare server functions to Server 2008 R2 and client OS functions to Windows 7. Anything else just doesn't produce any conclusive results in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A test you could do to see if it has to do with OS layer or lower would be to re-run the linux test while in a VM sitting on windows 7. If you experience numbers similar, but slightly less, then the original linux it proves Windows 7 is responsible. If you experience numbers similar to Windows 7 you may have a problem with the way windows 7 uses your hardware, potentially a driver issue or similar low level problem.

Comment: I'm not using VM. This is dual-boot setup

Answer (score -1):

Tetsting a static page with little to no content while using a limited number of connections is a bad test.

What you want to do is simulate 30+ users accessing pages that are both hitting PHP and MySQL with multiple assets.

In which case you'll see a well configured WAMP (like WampDeveloper, which is what I use) match or outperform a similar LAMP setup.

Under Windows, threads are the prefered mechanism (vs the process based models on Linux).

Make sure you are using PHP as a thread-based module (not FCGI process, though that would work too).

Edit your Apache KeepAlive and MPM settings...

C:\WampDeveloper\Config\Apache\extra\httpd-default.conf

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 1
```

C:\WampDeveloper\Config\Apache\extra\httpd-mpm.conf

```
ThreadsPerChild 64
ThreadLimit 64
```

This will set up about 64 threads, each keeping to the same client for about 1 second.

`ab -c 32 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1/page-with-PHP-and-MySQL-and-Assets.php`

Comment: Have I talked about PHP? Have I been talking about Sql? I've been talking about something very basic - at OS level HTTP client server that worked badly on Windows 7.

Comment: @Artyom, my fault for mis-understanding the premises of your question.